# Learning resources for a Rails developer working with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, silverlight

*What do I want to learn:*

- ASP.NET MVC
- Entity FrameWork
- Silver light

*What do I already know:*

- Ruby on Rails (so I know MVC as an architecture but in Rails)
- C#.NET language
- C#.NET WinForms
- WebStack like HTML, JS, jQuery, CSS

Please send me some "**books**" for references to begin with, not a fan of website,videos,blogs to start learning with.

Answer (score 2):

For **MVC**

1. **Programming.Microsoft.ASP.NET.MVC**
2. **Pro ASP.NET MVC**

For **Entity FrameWork**

1. **Oreilly.Programming.Entity.Framework.Code.First**

For **Silverlight**

1. **3d Game Development With Microsoft Silverlight**